# Can I use the onomatopoeic word 'tsuh' to mean disapproval?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, onomatopoeia

Can I use the onomatopoeic word 'tsuh'?

Not sure of its existence, I literally googled 'tsuh' to see if it was even a word. What I had in mind was a kind of exaggerated tongue click that one does as a sign of disapproval.

After browsing among Japanese terms, I found this definition by [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Tsuh) that does seem to give the word in question some sort of legitimacy.

*'An interjection expressing extreme indifference to or disdain of another person's ideas or presence. Also can be used to express displeasure about a situation. (Note: the T and S must both be clearly pronounced.)*

*Creepy guy: Hey girl you got pretty eyes, can I get your number?
Christine: Tsuh.*

*Steve: Dude check out my star wars toy collection!*

*Ted: Tsuh.*

*Jenny: WTF, this bar is out of Stoli Orange?!?*

*Mandy: TSUH!'*

I'm here to know how common this word is among English speakers and, possibly, if there are other spellings, or even altogether different words, that might better fit the context.

Comment: Googling the Web is good. You can also search https://books.google.com/. You can also search https://onelook.com/ to check dictionaries. Please include your results (including the one from UD) in your question, not in a link. (Links are not necessarily accessible to everyone, break over time, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can imagine that 'tsuh' is a rare alternative spelling of 'tsk' or 'tut'. These are derisive expressions originally written down to signify a tongue click, but some people use the spelling pronunciation and pronounce them literally as 'tisk' and 'tut'.

Comment: I remember as a kid seeing 'tsk-tsk' used in speech balloons in my favourite comics (_The Beano_ and _The Dandy_) usually when a adult was expressing disapproval, and failing to link it with the very familiar sound my parents used. I assumed it was local to Dundee, where the comics were published.

Answer (score 1):

People in the UK may use the word 'tut' as a verb (the act of making a specific sound expressing disapproval) or noun (the sound itself).

*My mother tuts every time she hears someone shouting in the street.*

*There was lots of tutting in the church when Joe wore a rainbow badge.*

*I heard lots of tuts in the train when the driver announced that it would be delayed.*

[Tut (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tut)

Answer (score 1):

There's also [tush](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tush) or *pish-tush*, an expression of contempt, now very old-fashioned. W.S. Gilbert called one of the characters in *The Mikado* Pish-Tush as a mock-Chinese name (the story is set in Japan, but he doesn't seem to have known the difference!).